# Error psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied even after postgres authorized connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, postgresql, psycopg2

My python script is raising an 'psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied' error, even though the Postgre server is authorizing the connect.

I am using Python 3.5, psycopg2, Postgre 9.5 and the password is stored in a .pgpass file.  The script is part of a restful flask application, using flask-restful.  The script is running on the same host as the Postgre server.

I am calling the connect function as follows:

```py
conn_admin = psycopg2.connect("dbname=database user=username")
```

When I execute the script I get the following stack trace:

```
   File "/var/www/flask/content_provider.py", line 84, in get_report
     conn_admin = psycopg2.connect("dbname=database user=username")
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

However when I look at the Postgre server log I see the following (I enabled the logger to also show all connection requests):

```
2019-01-04 18:28:35 SAST [17736-2] username@database LOG:  connection authorized: user=username database=database
```

This code is running fine on my development PC, however when I put it onto the Unbuntu server, I start getting this problem.

To try and find the issue, I have hard-coded the password into the connection string, but I still get the same error.

If I execute the above line directly into my Python terminal on the host, it works fine, with and without the password in the connection string.

EDIT:
One thing I did notice is that on my desktop I use Python 3.6.2, while on the server I use Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the host:

```
conn_admin = psycopg2.connect("dbname=database user=username host=localhost")
```

Comment: This worked perfect for me (though I am not exactly sure why).  Thanks.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 I had to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost: https://github.com/HazyResearch/fonduer-tutorials/issues/14

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar error below:

> psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Because I did not set `password` as shown below:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='postgres', user='postgres')
```

So, I put `password` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```py
conn = psycopg2.connect(database='postgres', user='postgres', password='admin')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the password ie
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=database user=username host=localhost password=password")